# How to create custom php.ini file ohn WHM

Tags: php, whm

I know I can edit the php.ini file via service configuration, but I want to know how can I can create a custom php.ini file for a specific subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup custom php.ini file with the .htaccess file by using **suPHP_ConfigPath**

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/public_html/sub_doamin_path
```